# bootstrap table header tooltip on hover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have table used with bootstrap table jquery plugin. But names of columns in header are quite long, and they don't fit and aren't displayed complete. F.e. column name in header:

> This is the long name of table column

But I getting only

> This is...

How to add bootstrap tooltip on hover which will display whole name?

Comment: Do you have those table cells with fixed width?

Comment: As you might expect, could you post an example code of where it happens?

Comment: There is nothing to post. It is regular html table with long titles of column. I just need a tooltip on hover of `<table><thead><tr><th>Very long title of column, that isn't displayed whole</th>` element

Comment: Have you tried using bootstrap's tooltips? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Answer (score 0):

```
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="This is the long name of table column">
```

Then in your onready code:

```
$('th[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

This what your looking for?